# inApp Purchase Titanium Android Using Module inAppBilling 3.0.1 not getting all required parameters

Tags: in-app-purchase, appcelerator, in-app-billing, subscription, appcelerator-titanium

I'm using the titanium module inAppBilling 3.0.1 For Android subscriptions and the app is in alpha testing, but I'm not getting the parameter called "autoRenewing".
The response I'm getting

```
    {   "orderId" : "",
        "packageName" : "com.dumy.in",
        "productId" : "subscribed',
        "purchaseTime" : 2016-17-2,
        "purchaseState" : 0,
        "purchaseToken" : dhbvhjbGHGHvdjksdkjsnkjvdj38365358njkxjsfjfsfHJGHJ,
```

}

and the response i want :

```
{                  "orderId" : "",
            "packageName" : "com.dumy.in",
            "productId" : "subscribed',
            "purchaseTime" : 2016-17-2,
            "purchaseState" : 0,
            "purchaseToken" : dhbvhjbGHGHvdjksdkjsnkjvdj38365358njkxjsfjfsfHJGHJ,
                        "autoRenewing" : true,
}
```

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.inappbilling/blob/5f74928643bcba216d5651aacce6a5d1a5e2bcca/android/src/ti/inappbilling/util/Purchase.java#L36-L48) it seems that the module is not passing that field on to you. Please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using your Google account as tester - check it in Google Play dashboard.

Make sure on the device you are testing there is only one Google account which is not a tester (I created a new account). It works for me.

- To test that this step is working try buying a consumable product you
  should see a Google dialog with a message saying this is a test
  purchase (or text similar). Once you delete the test account and log
  in with new one it should work.

Comment: Already tested with Live version but still not recevied parameter